# ASP/HTML Function to get data to asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

My Jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/adprodigy/tu9h6ww9/11/

html

```
<H4>Type</H4><select class="cbxSelect" name="Type" style="width:130px;" id="TypeN"><option value="Daily" selected="selected">Daily</option><option value="Weekly">Weekly</option><option value="Monthly">Monthly</option></select>'
```

So far I made it so that when I click execute I'm able to get the data selected in the box/form to show up on an alert message as "hours"~"LG","FG"~

I have a function in asp that requires two variable the Type and  Commodity.
I consider Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Hours, Minutes, Seconds as type
and everything listed under commodity as commodity.

I currently have a function that can get me one type and as many commodity as selected.
The same example as above "hours"~"LG","FG"~
(1 type and 2 commodities)

I need a code that identify the value in the alert message
"hours"~"LG","FG"~
to tell which one is type and which one is commodity so i can bring it in my function in asp.

Thanks

Comment: Include jQuery library in your fiddle.

Comment: where you are declaring these variables :- cbxCompany, cbxCommodity, cbxShop.

Comment: @stanze I'm declaring the cbx variable in JS. I use it to declare the div class and put the drop down where I want in html. What jquery am I missing?